# How to concatenate several short audio MP3 files with a specific overlap duration

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, mp3

I have MP3 files that tend to be very short, like 1 second, containing syllables of words. I would like to have an overlap (end of one merged with the beginning of the next one).  I have found several topics about crossfading but I am not sure I need it (crossfading), i.e., to lower the volume of one and raise the volume of the next one as we transition into it.  I think just a merge of the audio is enough at this time.

The overlap needs to be on the order of microseconds. I see FFmpeg has decimals of a seconds on some of the options.
Currently I am concatenating of bunch of short MP3s with the following:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// <para/>20170114
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public void ConcatMP3s(String InFiles, String OutputFile)
    {
        // http://superuser.com/questions/87040/how-to-stich-mp3s-together-with-ffmpeg
        var _IN_PARAMS = " -f concat ";
        var _IN_FILES = "-safe 0 -i " + DQuote(InFiles);
        var _OUT_PARAMS = " -c copy -y ";  // -y to overwrite the output file
        var _OUT_FILE = DQuote(OutputFile);
        //
        var _FFMPEG_ARGS = _IN_PARAMS + _IN_FILES + _OUT_PARAMS + _OUT_FILE;
        //return _FFMPEG_ARGS;
        //
        RunFFmpeg(_FFMPEG_ARGS);
    }
```

I would like a command or technique that will concatenate several files at once, but if you show me how to do it for two files, I can loop through all of them. It's an ugly but acceptable answer :).

@Mulvya, what I could grab from your link is the following FFmpeg command line structure (all in one command line string)

```
ffmpeg -i 1.mp3 -i 2.mp3 -i 3.mp3 -i 4.mp3
   -filter_complex
     "[1]adelay=delay1|delay1[b];
      [2]adelay=delay2|delay2[c];
      [3]adelay=delay3|delay3[d];
      [0][b][c][d]amix=4"
merged.mp3
```

What do delay1, delay2, and delay3 need to be?  Are they the durations in milliseconds of `1.mp3`, `2.mp3`, and `3.mp3` respectively?

What is the best way to retrieve these durations?  e.g., are file-system file properties accurate?

Are the letters [b], [c], [d] something arbitrary? channel-names? I will need to generate?

Where do I specify, for example, 10 milliseconds overlap between `1.mp3` and `2.mp3`, 2 and 3, and then 3 and 4?

Or should I minus 10 milliseconds from delay1, delay2, delay3?

Addition: here is a snapshot of a manual montage I put together to explain what I am trying to achieve programmatically (assume a constant overlap; here I am trying about 100 ms).  Please explain what values for delay1, delay2, delay3 above should be.

[image: snapshot of a manual montage]

MP3 durations from FFmpeg output are 550, 440, 500, 960, 440 ms respectively.

=========
Current Output from FFmpeg

`_VDO\FFmpeg 20160310\bin\FFmpeg  -i "S:\_W\ARP_WEB\SRC\SND\A4_23\1\01.mp3" -i "S:\_W\ARP_WEB\SRC\SND\A2\1\22.mp3" -i "S:\_W\ARP_WEB\SRC\SND\A2\3\23.mp3" -i "S:\_W\ARP_WEB\SRC\SND\A3\1\24.mp3" -i "S:\_W\ARP_WEB\SRC\SND\A2\2\03.mp3" -filter_complex "[1]adelay=279[b];[2]adelay=592[c];[3]adelay=916[d];[4]adelay=1712[e]; [0][b][c][d][e]amix=5" -y "S:\_W\ARP\AMSSTUDIO\SRC\DATA\FFMPEG\DEBUG Concat with Overlap\OUT.MP3"`

`ffmpeg version N-79000-g66edd86 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 5.3.0 (GCC)
configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libdcadec --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmfx --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
libavutil 55. 19.100 / 55. 19.100
libavcodec 57. 28.100 / 57. 28.100
libavformat 57. 28.100 / 57. 28.100
libavdevice 57. 0.101 / 57. 0.101
libavfilter 6. 39.102 / 6. 39.102
libswscale 4. 0.100 / 4. 0.100
libswresample 2. 0.101 / 2. 0.101
libpostproc 54. 0.100 / 54. 0.100
[mp3 @ 0000000000584ba0] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, mp3, from 'S:\_W\ARP_WEB\SRC\SND\A4_23\1\01.mp3':
Duration: 00:00:00.55, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 320 kb/s
Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, mono, s16p, 320 kb/s
[mp3 @ 00000000005a2a20] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #1, mp3, from 'S:\_W\ARP_WEB\SRC\SND\A2\1\22.mp3':
Duration: 00:00:00.44, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 320 kb/s
Stream #1:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, mono, s16p, 320 kb/s
[mp3 @ 000000000058af00] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #2, mp3, from 'S:\_W\ARP_WEB\SRC\SND\A2\3\23.mp3':
Duration: 00:00:00.50, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 320 kb/s
Stream #2:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, mono, s16p, 320 kb/s
[mp3 @ 000000000058cb80] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #3, mp3, from 'S:\_W\ARP_WEB\SRC\SND\A3\1\24.mp3':
Duration: 00:00:00.96, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 127 kb/s
Stream #3:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, mono, s16p, 128 kb/s
[mp3 @ 00000000005c5c00] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #4, mp3, from 'S:\_W\ARP_WEB\SRC\SND\A2\2\03.mp3':
Duration: 00:00:00.44, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 320 kb/s
Stream #4:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, mono, s16p, 320 kb/s
Output #0, mp3, to 'S:\_W\ARP\AMSSTUDIO\SRC\DATA\FFMPEG\DEBUG Concat with Overlap\OUT.MP3':
Metadata:
TSSE : Lavf57.28.100
Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3 (libmp3lame), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp (default)
Metadata:
encoder : Lavc57.28.100 libmp3lame
Stream mapping:
Stream #0:0 (mp3) -> amix:input0
Stream #1:0 (mp3) -> adelay
Stream #2:0 (mp3) -> adelay
Stream #3:0 (mp3) -> adelay
Stream #4:0 (mp3) -> adelay
amix -> Stream #0:0 (libmp3lame)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Error while filtering: Cannot allocate memory
size= 5kB time=00:00:00.54 bitrate= 70.2kbits/s speed=42.3x 
video:0kB audio:4kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 4.938003%`

Comment: Merging audio with overlap isn't that different from crossfading, and crossfading will give better results. You can do that e.g. with [sox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28652490/cross-fading-several-audio-files-using-sox), but you may need to convert to `.wav` files first (which can be done in batch). Mp3 files encode audio in frames of a certain length, so you might not be able to do microsecond-scale overlapping audio in mp3 without re-encoding, anyway.

Comment: The answer [here](http://superuser.com/q/1092291/114058) can be adapted.

Comment: You have created two user accounts.  You should merge them.  [this](http://superuser.com/users/690627/marie) account created question but your now using [this](http://superuser.com/users/690629/marie) account.

Comment: I've edited for now, but yeah, you really need to ask for a merge, rather than posting what should be edits as an answer @marie

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  As others have said, it would appear that you have accidentally created two accounts.  Use the [contact form](/contact) and select “I need to merge user profiles” to have your accounts merged.  In order to merge them, you will need to provide links to the two accounts.  For your information, these are http://superuser.com/users/690627/marie and http://superuser.com/users/690629/marie.  You’ll then be able to [edit], comment on, and accept answers to this question.

Comment: Thank you, I think the accounts are now merged.  Commenting on an answer seems to be limited to few lines.   Where am I expected to post a listing from an output or such? I ended up appending it to the base post, but this feels not naturelle :).

Comment: (1) You did the right thing; any information that is required to understand the question should be part of the question. (2) I see that the screenshot you posted lists clip lengths of 549, 444, 496, 967 and 444 ms.  Your question text lists durations of 550, 440, 500, 960, 440 ms.  I guess these are the same numbers, rounded to the nearest multiple of ten.  But, since your question includes both sets of numbers, it would be nice if you explained that the second set was rounded.  Otherwise, it’s confusing.

Comment: The durations from the screenshot are from Wavelab and the rounded ones are from FFmpeg output. I did not realize they are rounded :).  I read around that it is not trivial to retrieve mp3 durations and also because of VBR.  Lot's of this sound encoding is above my head, I am just trying to make a crude and systematic text to speech library.  Ideally, for my particular concatenation I wished the ffmpeg as sophisticated as it is would save me from having to specify the durations and simply accepted an overlap specification perhaps with the -copy and not necessarily the -filter_complex one.

Comment: Continued:  something like ffmpeg -i filelist.txt -concat "delay=100"  and  ffmpeg -i filelist.txt -concat "delay=100; [3]delay=50;" to have a global delay and a specific delay for specific input files.  If not specified then default to zero.  I will probably build the wrapper to achieve this. Such a specification support would be useful to use and prototype from a simple scripting like Windows command line  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a command of the form

```
ffmpeg -i 1.mp3 -i 2.mp3 -i 3.mp3 -i 4.mp3
   -filter_complex
     "[1]adelay=delay1|delay1[b];
      [2]adelay=delay2|delay2[c];
      [3]adelay=delay3|delay3[d];
      [0][b][c][d]amix=4"
merged.mp3
```

Each `delayN` in milliseconds is the starting offset of an audio from the start of the audio stream. So, if you want file2 to start at 14.2 seconds of the final mix, use `adelay=14200|14200` for a stereo input. You can use `adelay=14200` for a mono input. In your screenshot, these are the Start column values.

The label pads `[a]` ..etc are arbitrary and assigned to the outputs of filters so that they can be used later in other filters or mapped for output. Each pad can be consumed once. They are alphanumeric but avoid assigning pure integers like `[2]` since ffmpeg uses those to refer to the input files.

Comment: below  is the command line I am attempting to prototype with according to your explanation.  I used the start column values and mono.  ffmpeg seems to fail allocating memory? and barely mixes the first two files when I view the waveform.

Also, please let me know what is the best way to obtain the durations of these files, Windows file property dialog seem to show 00:00:00 but I have not attempted to actually query the filesystem API (hopefully it's only trimming the fractional part of the seconds in the "humans" dialog).
(See tail of base post, I can't type here anymore)

Comment: Upgrade ffmpeg and try. Your ffmpeg is over 4000 commits old. If it still fails, run with `-report` added. Link to the report file.